# Not able to read jceks file in yarn cluster mode in python

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, jceks

I am using a jceks file to decrypt my password and unable to read the encrypted password in  yarn cluster mode

I have tried different methods like included

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster 
--file /localpath/credentials.jceks#credentials.jceks
--conf spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://file////localpath/credentials.jceks test.py
```

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName("xyz").master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
x = spark1.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
x.set("hadoop.security.credential.provider.path", "jceks://file///credentials.jceks")
a = x.getPassword("<password alias>")
passw = ""
for i in range(a.__len__()):
   passw = passw + str(a.__getitem__(i))
```

I am getting the below error:

> attributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**len**'

and when I am printing a ,it has None

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if you try putting your jceks file to hdfs, the yarn workers would be able to find it while running on cluster mode, at least it works for me. Hope it works for you.

```
hadoop fs -put ~/.jceks /user/<uid>/.jceks
```

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName("xyz").master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
x = spark1.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
jceks_hdfs_path = "jceks://hdfs@<host>/user/<uid>/.jceks"
x.set("hadoop.security.credential.provider.path", jceks_hdfs_path)
a = x.getPassword("<password alias>")
passw = ""
for i in range(a.__len__()):
   passw = passw + str(a.__getitem__(i))
```

With that you won't need to specify --files and --conf in the arguments when you run spark-submit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to jceks like this

#Choosing jceks from spark staging directory

```
jceks_location=“jceks://“ + str(“/user/your_user_name/.sparkStaging/“ + str(spark.sparkContest.applicationId) + “/credentials.jceks“)

x.set("hadoop.security.credential.provider.path",jceks_location)
```